# FreeBSD snmpd on a single interface

Tags: freebsd, snmp

I have a FreeBSD host with multiple IP interfaces. I would like to have snmpd listen on a single private IP interface, but I am getting the following error when trying to start the service.

*Error opening specified endpoint "192.168.200.50"*

in my configuration file I have the following line

```
agentaddress  192.168.200.50
```

If I remove this line, snmpd starts up fine, but is listening on all interfaces, which I would like to avoid.

I have generated the configuration file with snmpconf, and it fails when I specify the IP address to listen on via the script.

Any thoughts on how to correct this?

This is on FreeBSD 8.3-STABLE and net-snmp 5.7.1

Thanks